# Cambiar formato de Date/Time pickers material ui

Tags: reactjs

Cuando se ingresa una fecha en un texfield de tipo type="datetime-local" el formato para ingresar a fecha es mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --

¿Hay alguna manera de cambiarlo a yyyy/mm/dd --:-- --?

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate>
  <TextField
    id="datetime-local"
    label="Next appointment"
    type="datetime-local"
    defaultValue="2017-05-24T10:30"
    className={classes.textField}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
    }}
  />
</form>
```